# Malloc vairables in seperate function results in "uninitialized in this function"

Tags: c, variables, malloc, warnings, compiler-warnings

Trying to simplify my code and I thought I'd be smart by mallocing all the variables in a function in a seperate function to remove big code chunks. However when I try to malloc some variables, the compiler returns:

> warning: ‘roomString’ is used uninitialized in this function
>   [-Wuninitialized]

Heres the shortened code:

```
int main(){
    char ** roomString;
    mallocBoard(roomString);
    return 0;
}
void mallocBoard(char ** roomString)
{
    roomString = malloc(sizeof(char *) *PARSEBUFF);
}
```

Just wondering why its returning a warning? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: apparently you need the `***` tree stars... Or just `char **mallocBoard(size_t size) { return malloc(sizeo(char *) * size);}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because `roomString` is uninitialized in `main()`.

When you pass the `roomString` pointer to the `mallocBoard` function, it does not overwrite the address sotred in the poitner, but instead the one stored in the local pointer passed to `mallocBoard()` and that is because in c you always pass variables by value.

I mean that the `roomString` received as a parameter in `mallocBoard()` is a copy of the original poitner, it just contains the same address of the original pointer in `main()` points too, but a different address of it's own, so modifiying it's value does not modify the value of the pointer in `main()`.

You have 2 options

1. Pass the address of the poitner to `mallocBoard()` like this

   ```
   void mallocBoard(char ***pointer, size_t size)
    {
       *pointer = malloc(sizeof(char *) * size);
    }
   ```

   and then from `main()`

   ```
   mallocBoard(&roomString, someSize);
   ```

   that will modify the value of the original pointer.
2. Return the new `malloc()`ed pointer from the `mallocBoard()` like this

   ```
   char **mallocBoard(size_t size)
    {
       return malloc(sizeof(char *) * size);
    }
   ```

   and then in `main()`

   ```
   roomString = mallocBoard(someSize);
   ```

Answer (score 0):

When `roomString` in main is passed to `mallocBoard`, a copy of the variable `roomString` is created and placed into `mallocBoard`'s parameter. Then, when malloc is called, the pointer value that is returned by malloc is stored into the local variable `roomString` which is not the same as the variable `roomString` in the main method, and the `roomString` value in main is never initialized.

To solve this problem, it is probably best to not put the call to `malloc` inside its own function because (1) This function is of limited use and unlikely to be needed elsewhere in your code: it only allocates an array of character pointers of a set size, and (2) there is some overhead each time you call a function (placing the parameters on the stack, saving the return address etc) so it is probably not worth it to call a function just to execute a single line.

Also `malloc` returns a pointer to `void`, so it is best to explicitly cast the value returned by `malloc` to the type you want: `roomString = (char **) malloc(sizeof(char*) * PARSEBUFF);`